# problems with truecrypt folder

Tags: truecrypt

I'm afraid that I don't even have the knowledge to express what my problem is. When I open up my Truecrypt folder it loads just fine at first; then the bar at the top starts to fill in from left to right; most of the icons disappear with nothing but the name of the folder left. No folders or shortcuts will open up. then this phenomena transfers to the rest of my computer (W7 pro.) It scared the heck out me the first time it happened, but all I have to do is reboot and everything is fine until I open the truecrypt folder again. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Any chance you could post some kind of a screen shot of what the after effect looks like?

Comment: Did it work before? Is TrueCrypt up to date?

Comment: The fact that you call it "Truecrypt folder" and not a TrueCrypt encrypted volume makes me think you're actually clicking on something that's pretending to be a TrueCrypt volume (some variant of the infamous [LNK:Runner trojan](http://www.enigmasoftware.com/lnkrunnerb-removal/) maybe?)